# Python: How to find out if an unknown element exists in a list?

Tags: python, numpy

`zero_crossings2` basically detects sign changes. 
If there is a `zero_crossings2` I want to append `1` to crossing_list, otherwise I want to append a `0` to crossing_list. 
The code `np.where(np.diff(np.sign(a2)))[0]` can determine the index of the sign change. So if it returns a result I want to return a "1" at that specific position and a "0" everywhere it does not detect a sign change.

Here is the current state of my code:

```
import numpy as np
crossing_list = []
a2 = [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, -3, -4, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, 1, -3, 5, 6, 7, -10]
zero_crossings2 = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(a2)))[0]


for i in range(len(a2)):
    if X in zero_crossings2[i]:
        crossing_list.append('1')
    else:
        crossing_list.append('0')

crossing_list_new = np.array(crossing_list)
```

What I am having trouble with is in the if-statement, the "X" is unknown so I do not know which element is in the list.

My expected output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: `np.where(np.diff(np.sign(a2)), 1, 0)` will do the trick. You may want to add a `0` at the beginning though. It depends on how you want to treat the sign of `0` though.

Comment: Title and body seems confusing, but `np.r_[0,np.diff(np.array(a2)>=0)]` seems to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the array you want, you can do:

```
a2 = [1, 2, 1, 1, 0, -3, -4, 7, 8, 9, 10, -2, 1, -3, 5, 6, 7, -10]
signs = np.sign(a2)
crossings = np.where(np.diff(signs), 1, 0)
```

The first zero is missing (because the first number of `crossings` corresponds to the crossing of the first and the second number of `a2`), so you can add it with this:

```
crossings = np.insert(crossings, 0, 0)
```